# Symfony2 - FOSFacebook Bundle - Subdomain 

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, fosfacebookbundle

So I've mangaged to get the FOSFacebook bundle integrated into my app alongside the FOSUser bundle. Now it's working properly on my dev server minus a few bugs but it works.

**UPDATE:** So for some reason facebook is setting the cookie to mysite.com.au instead of subdomain.mysite.com which means that it fails to pick up on the cookie and goes to the default failure page which is /facebook/login.

Now for some reason when I deployed it to my live server, which has the same address(I'm changing my hosts file to simulate the domain) when I try to login I get
"No route found for "GET /facebook/login"
If I try to access this page on the dev, I get the same message, but normally it logs me in and then redirects me to the index.
On the live it gets stuck on /facebook/login

Here's my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        "FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface": sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager
        my_fos_facebook_provider:
            id: my.facebook.user
    factories:
      - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle/Resources/config/security_factories.xml"
    firewalls:
        public:
            pattern:   ^/
            fos_facebook:
                app_url: "(set to the apps.facebook link I have)"
                server_url: "http://testbed.mysite.com/app_dev.php/"
                check_path: /facebook/check
                login_path: /facebook/login
                default_target_path: /
                provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
            form_login:
                success_handler: authentication_handler
                failure_handler: authentication_handler
                provider: fos_userbundle
            anonymous: true
            logout: true



    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/testing/secure/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/secure/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/account, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

If you need a look at any other files, let me know

Obviously there is no route for /facebook/login but I believe it's supposed to be that way.
Any ideas people?

Comment: You have to define check_path AND login_path as routes in your routing configuration

Comment: I have check_path defined as a blank route and that works fine. If I set login_path to a blank route symfony complains that the route is empty. If I attach a controller action to it and render a template it just renders the template and doesnt do anything after that. What is strange is that on my dev site, it appears to forward to the login page but symfony handles this correctly. On my live server it just gets stuck on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Just define login_path as the default path set up in the security.yml :

```
_security_login:
    pattern:  /login
    requirements:
        _scheme:  https

_security_check:
    pattern:  /login_check
    requirements:
        _scheme:  https

_security_logout:
    pattern:  /logout
    requirements:
        _scheme:  https
```

You can define your own controller for login_path if you need some specific treatment but you don't have to !

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that somehow on my live site I'd forgotten to setup parameters.ini correctly and as such whenever I attempted to login it'd fail but never actually fully fail.